# Filter Array with UISearchBar

Tags: arrays, swift, uisearchbar

I am currently using the following code to filter the array and present the results in my tableView. The problem is that this only returns results if the search matches the exact word. How do I change my array filter to search each character as I type it?

```
let data = ["Mango", "Grape", "Berry", "Orange", "Apple"]

var filteredData: [String] = []

filteredData = data.filter({$0 == searchBar.text})
```

The only way to get "Mango" to show up in my tableView, I have to type Mango in the search bar, typing "Man" doesn't show any results.

Comment: use contains instead of ==
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1643241-contains

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
filteredData  = data.filter { $0.contains(_ other: searchBar.text) }
```

Answer (score 7):

Swift 5 Solution:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    filteredData = data

    if searchText.isEmpty == false {
        filteredData = data.filter({ $0.contains(searchText) })
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

This ensures that when the searchBar is empty, it goes back to displaying all your array's data, while also reloading the tableView every time you change the text.

Answer (score 0):

This will surely help you out:

var filteredData: [String] = []

```
 func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText:String){
    filterContentForSearchText(searchText: searchText)
}

func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    if searchText != "" {

        filterData = data.filter {name in

                                return   name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())

        }
    }else { self.filterData = self.data}
}
```